# Android SDK "no such file" while file exists

Tags: android, linux, intellij-idea, android-sdk-tools, linux-mint

I just migrated from Windows to Linux Mint. I downloaded the SDK and started using it. AVD manager is working, and I'm even able to start from intellij, but when I asked to launch some device it said me:

Starting emulator for AVD 'Pakon'

> Failed to start emulator: Cannot run program 
>   "/home/marcinm/Programy/sdk/tools/emulator": error=2,  No such file or
>   directory

While I checked and there is such file in this directory.

Also when I want to compile project the error message is saying to me:

> Error:android-apt-compiler: Cannot run program 
>   "/home/marcinm/Programy/sdk/build-tools/19.1.0/aapt":  error=2, No
>   such file or directory

While there also is aapt file on this directory.

Anyone has idea how to fix it?

UPDATE:

I found the solution. There must be package provided. I fixed it by changing code to:

```
    @Test
    fun simpleGenerationTest() {
        val beforeProcess = "com.example.activitystarter.MainActivity" to """
package com.example.activitystarter;

import android.app.Activity;
import activitystarter.MakeActivityStarter;

@MakeActivityStarter
public class MainActivity extends Activity {}
        """

        val afterProcess = "com.example.activitystarter.MainActivityStarter" to """
package com.example.activitystarter;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.annotation.UiThread;

public class MainActivityStarter {
    @UiThread
    public static void fill(MainActivity activity) {
    }

    @UiThread
    public static void start(Context context) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
    context.startActivity(intent);
    }

    @UiThread
    public static void startWithFlags(Context context, int flags) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(flags);
    context.startActivity(intent);
    }

    @UiThread
    public static Intent getIntent(Context context) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
    return intent;
    }
}
        """

        processingComparator(beforeProcess, afterProcess)
    }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Are you running a 64-bit version? As per [here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/index.html) it seems that you need to install some 32 bit libraries:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libncurses5:i386 libstdc++6:i386 zlib1g:i386
```

Comment: @PhilippeDavid Click Stand-alone SDK Tools > Show Instructions for all platforms > Troubleshooting Ubuntu, you should see it there. There's no direct link to that.

Answer (score 0):

check this:

```
sudo apt-get install     libc6-i386   lib32stdc++6   lib32z1   lib32gcc1   lib32ncurses5
```